# SL4A app works using adb not apk

Tags: android, python, sl4a

I have a simple scrip which opens a webpage. It works fine while using the adb start command; however, it seems to crash and exit when you attempt to implement using the apk. The app starts but after a button is pressed, it closes. Nothing happens. Any ideas?

Comment: Please post the ADB command that works and the relevant code snippets from your APK. This will help us solve your problem.

Comment: What does the LogCat output for the launch of the App tell you?